# popup windows doesn't open again when closed

Tags: jquery

I've used a popup window for my website.The popup window is actually for change password..
When I fill data to change password, it works perfectly...
Given the link to popup as:

```
<div id="abc"></div>
<div>
    <a href="#" class="passwordlink" data-id=" Model.ProfileView.Password">Change Password</a>
</div>
```

The moment I close the popup using close button on right top [x], without actually filling any data (suppose when mistakenly opened), and try once again to open it, nothing happens..The popup just stops working..
I get a hash[#] appended in the url when this happens, when I manually remove it every time, popup works, else it doesn't..
Any idea how I should go about, if I remove # from href, instead of removing it from url, popup lasts only for a few seconds and closes itself...

My complete code:
    
    
    Change Password

```
<script src="~/Scripts/app-password.js/passwordupdate.js"></script>
```

In script folder:
1)To open popup-containing a partial view(called PasswordUpdate) to change password..This view has fields to change password,close button on right top[x] and a save button..

```
$("#abc").dialog({
autoOpen: false,
modal: true,
width: 450,
title: "Password Updation"
});

$(".passwordlink").click(function () {
var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
$.ajax({
    // Call CreatePartialView action method
    url: "/Channel/PasswordUpdate",
    type: 'Get',
    data: { Password: id },
    success: function (data) {
        $("#abc").dialog("open");
        $("#abc").append(data);

    },
    error: function () {
        alert("something seems wrong");
    }
});
});
```

My partialview in popup:
    @model StudiModel.StudiPasswordUpdation

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div style="text-align: center">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Password Updation</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            Current Password
            <div id="currentpassword">
                @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.currentPassword)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.currentPassword)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            New Password
            <div id="newpassword">
                @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.newPassword)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.newPassword)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            Confirm New Password
            <div id="confirmnewpassword">
                @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.confirmNewPassword)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.confirmNewPassword)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="submit-button"></div>
        <div class="form"><div class="link_right"><button type="submit" class="orange" value="Save">Save</button></div></div>           
    </div>
</div>


<div class="footer"></div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/accodation-styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/datepicker.css">
<link href="~/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/js/accodation-script.js"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript">      </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/app-password.js/passwordpartial.js"></script>   
}
```

On click of save button in PasswordUpdate partial view in popup, update of password happens..
    $("#submit-button").click(function () {
    // On submit button click close dialog box
    $("#abc").dialog("close");

```
//Set inserted vlaues
var currentpassword = $("#currentpassword").val();
var newpassword = $("#newassword").val();
var confirmnewpassword = $("#confirmnewpassword").val();

// Call Create action method
$.post('~/Channel/PasswordUpdate', { "currentpassword": currentpassword, "newpassword":  newpassword, "confirmnewpassword": confirmnewpassword },
    function (data) {
        alert("data is posted successfully");
        window.location.reload(true);

    });
});
```

So far its good..The problem is close button,open popup and close without entering values using close button[x], the link "change password" stops working unless the page is loaded again...

Comment: We need to show your `Javascript/jQuery` code.

Comment: My code:<div id="abc"></div>
<div>
<a href="#" class="passwordlink" data-id=" Model.ProfileView.Password">Change Password</a>
</div> My

Comment: I've edited my code in the post..Hope it helps you to answer me back..

Answer (score 0):

Just use `href=""` instead of `href="#"` should do it.

Btw.: why do u use a `<a>-Tag?`

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can use data-role:popup attribute,

```
<a href="#myPopup" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all">Show Popup</a>

<div data-role="popup" id="myPopup">
"ur code"
</div>
```